Identifying equilibrium point of a time series
I am working on a piece of analysis around new product releases, and specifically whether the lifecycle of new product releases has changed over time.
One question I am interested in is statistical approaches for identifying when a new product reaches equilibrium. Typically, for each new product, we see an initial surge in revenue that eventually reaches some sort of equilibrium point. From what I've seen, most approaches require knowing what the equilibrium point is, which in this case, we don't know.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

It would be helpful to see the nature of the time series. Is there a typical pattern? How noisy are the data relative to the range of change?

@MichaelLew -- this is for work so I'm not able to share the time series, but ultimately I will be looking at this over thousands (if not more) time series so the noise will vary depending on the product. that said, the typical pattern is that the product will trend sharply upwards post release, and then begin to decline over a given period. the data can be noisy, in the past i've used an exponential moving average to help mitigate the noise. lmk if that helps with your question and appreciate your help here

Actually more of a comment, but with my current score I am not allowed to comment, so I have to write this as an answer.
I guess it depends on what exactly you define as equilibrium. My first guess would be something like random fluctuations around a stable mean. Depending on what you allow for these fluctuations, you could try to test when your process becomes stationary or white noise (informally speaking). I would do this backwards, starting with the most current value and then expand the window to the left hand side. I think the test should yield non-stationarity/non-white noise after reaching the point where the equilibrium start (again speaking informally). Also you dont necessarily have to test, you could also just look for the point where the deviation between sample means is bigger than one standard deviation or something similar. There you dont have theoretical guarantees however.
I think these ideas probably fit in the literature of structural breaks and control charts for time series, you may find more detailed (and formal) answers there.

thank you! this is so beautifully obvious. will comment back if i have more questions once i attempt this.
